# div isn't clickable after making a choice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I click on the link #S1, a modal appears with a list on it. Then I click on one of the items from the list to send various information to the page. It works just fine. However, when I click once again on the #S1 link nothing happens. What did I do wrong?

Here is the html code

```
<div class="slot" id="slot1">
    <div class="image">
        <a href="#"><span class="circled" id="S1"></span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the onclick fonction

```
$('#S1').click(function(){
    openModal();
    modalContent(1);
    showList(1)
    return false;
});
```

Here is the openModal function

```
function openModal() {
    el = document.getElementById("modal");
    el.style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

Here is the modalContent function

```
function modalContent(id) {
    switch(id) {
        case 1:
            $("#modal").load("modal.php");
            break;
    } 
}
```

Here is the showList function

```
function showList(id) {
    if (id=="") {
        document.getElementById("list").innerHTML="";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } 
    else {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("list").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","list.php?slot="+id,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Here is the list.php code

```
$slot = intval($_GET['slot']);
if($slot == 1){
    $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM item ORDER BY level DESC");
    $result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    echo '<table class="tableau">';

    while($row = $result->fetch()){
        echo '<tr onclick="itemInfo('.$row->id.')">';
            echo '<td width="10%">'.$row->level.'</td>';
            echo '<td width="90%">'.$row->name.'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }

    echo '</table>';
}
```

And here is the itemInfo function

```
function itemInfo(id) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } 
    else {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById('slot1').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","itemChoice.php?item="+id,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    document.getElementById('modal').innerHTML = '';
    document.getElementById('modal').style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: you're using jquery... why are you rolling your own xmlhttprequest stuff? Why not just `$.get()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I first noticed that you do not have a semicolon after `showList(1)` in the `click` function. Have you checked the error console in your browser to see if the click isn't working because of a JS error?

But also, I noticed that you tagged this with `jquery` but you are barely using it. Here is your javascript code refactored with jQuery:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#S1').click(function(){
        openModal();
        modalContent(1);
        showList(1);
        return false;
    });
});

function openModal() {
    $("#modal").show();
}

function modalContent(id) {
    switch(id) {
        case 1:
            $("#modal").load("modal.php");
            break;
    } 
}

function itemInfo(id) {
    $.get("itemChoice.php?item="+id, function(data) {
        $("#slot1").html(data);
    });
    $("#modal").hide().html("");
}

function showList(id) {
    $.get("list.php?slot="+id, function(data) {
        $("#list").html( data );
    });
}
</script>
```

Oh yeah, and unless there is a specific reason to use the `visibility` style, leave it alone and use `display: none;` and `display: block;`. The jQuery `show()` and `hide()` function uses `display` and not `visibility`.

Comment: There is no error shown on the console on firebug. However, there is something strange. At first, when I inspect the link, the click event is shown on the events list. Then, when I click it and make my choice, the click event isn't there anymore and it tells me "There are no event listeners directly on this element."

Comment: As a test, why don't you try putting the click event on the `a` instead of the `span`: `$("#S1").parent().click(...`. Since your html code snippet shows that the `span` tag has no text, I'm betting that you have some other code that is putting something in there. That code is not in your example and could be the source of the problem.

Comment: Another question: the block of html with the S1 span, is it being reloaded by any of the other actions? If those html elements are being removed from the DOM and re-added, that will cause the click binding to be lost. You can do `$("body").on("click", "span#S1", function() {...` in place of the current handle to catch the event.

Comment: Yeah the span is reloaded by itemInfo. I did what you said in your last comment and now it's working. Thanks :)

Comment: No problem.... figured this one out the hard way myself once. Use `on` with the filter option anytime you're creating events for DOM objects that will be added or removed dynamically.